# How to find the speed of a boat needed to become airborne on a wave

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, dynamics

I am doing a small dynamic project that needs to predict the boat's (boat with propeller) movements in a wavy sea condition as shown below:

[image]

as the boat is at the peak of the wave, how to determine how much would be the boat's speed for it to fly away from the water? (how will it move...)

**the known information are:**

1 wave's speed in x and y direction at the peak point is 0.5 m/s and 0.4 m/s respectively, boat's hp is 100.

2 boat's velocity (3 m/s - 5 m/s ), weight (250kg) , size (cross sectional area immersed in water is 0.081 m^2 , volume immersed in water is 0.244 m^3, height of boat is 2m, length 3m and width 1m)

3 wave's height 0.3m, length 3m.

4 drag coefficient is 0.09.

5 viscosity of water is  8.90 × 10−4Pa·s

6 boat's buoyancy

7 water's drag force (needs to be used)

(the air friction can be neglected, use pure water density)

**calculation:**

in y direction: I calculated the buoyancy force and found it to be 2452.5 N same as the weight in calm water. when the wave hits and rises the boat which formula should I use to calculate the force being applied to the boat in the y direction?

in x direction : I calculated drag force using this formula:

[image]

and found it to be 4478.985N , but I am not very sure how to find the the force of the boat, so that I can compare it with the drag force, if the value is larger , then will the boat would fly away from the boat?

please help me with the concept of how to solve this problem....

if any information is missing, please inform me... I will update....
Thanks...

Comment: You need to ask a specific question. If that is "what does a boat's speed need to be to become airborne on a wave" put that in the title. Also you need to include the known values if they are truly known. The people on this site can help you understand a concept or point you in the right direction, but they will not do a homework problem for you.

Comment: Thank you ericnutsch, for your advise... sorry its my first time asking question on the  website, didnt know how to explain very well... I have updated the question, please have a look...

Comment: There are lots of things going on here. I assume this is a homework problem? It is not clear what is being asked. I would focus on the geometric portion of the problem; wave shape vs projectile motion. If you are trying to find the speed, the drag does not matter. The drag only matters when calculating how much power it takes to maintain that speed. Also buoyancy is zero when it leaves the water so ignore that. Good luck!